# Can't navigate to nib iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, exc-bad-access, nib

This is my code to navigate to another nib,

```
  MaintenanceViewController *maintenance = [[MaintenanceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MaintenanceViewController" bundle:nil];
  CGRect theFrame = maintenance.view.frame;
  theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0);
  maintenance.view.frame = theFrame;
  theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0);
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6f];
  maintenance.view.frame = theFrame;
  [UIView commitAnimations];
  [self.view addSubview:maintenance.view];
```

note that I am not using navigation controller and also I dont want to as my app is not based on navigation.

When This method is called on second line i.e. getting frame(theframe) the app got crashed with error  `Exec_bad_access code=2 address = 0xbf7ffffc`.

So nib couldn't loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first; your app is crashing because you are having a call on a `nill` variable: maintenance. You need to ensure that the loading of your nib file is happening correctly.

There are different reasons this is not happening; check:

> 1. You are using the correct name for the xib and the file exist.
> 2. You have defined correctly the xib file's "File owner": your view controller.

Second thing; i think what you want is to present modally your second view controller which can be accomplished by making a call to the presenting view controller with the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method.

Comment: I have connected properly though I am facing the issue.
And please explain in code what you want to say.
Thanks

Comment: @ParasGorasiya did u debug and check that the value of maintenance is non nul?

Comment: The source code from Wezly is correct...but before once again make sure maintenance is not nil

Comment: I have checked using if(maintenance == NULL) but sadly it is not null

Answer (score 3):

Check this Sample [`SlideMenu`](https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu)

It may help to solve your issue

Answer (score 2):

To navigate to another viewController you should use the `presentViewController` method like this:

```
MaintenanceViewController *maintenance = [[MaintenanceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MaintenanceViewController" bundle:nil];
[maintenance setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[self presentViewController:maintenance
                   animated:YES
                 completion:^(void){
                 }
 ];
```

Also, depending on how you setup your MaintenanceViewController you may not need to use `initWithNibName`

```
MaintenanceViewController *maintenance = [[MaintenanceViewController alloc] init];
```

Comment: thanks but your solution couldnt help me, the issue is still there.